# Rails ActionController::UnknownFormat error with respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm getting this error, when trying to use ajax.  I did some searching, but couldn't solve my problem

`ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Drafts Controller:

```
  def index
    if params["format"] != nil
      @draft = Draft.find_by(id: params["format"].to_i)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
    @draft = current_user.drafts.build
    @drafts = current_user.drafts.non_submitted
    @being_edited_drafts = current_user.drafts.being_edited
    @completed_drafts = current_user.drafts.completed
  end
```

index.js.erb

```
$('.draft_<%= @draft.id %>').trigger('click');
```

log:

```
Started GET "/drafts.132" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-26 11:56:28 -0800
Processing by DraftsController#index as 
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 4  ORDER BY     "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Draft Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "drafts".* FROM "drafts"  WHERE "drafts"."id" = 132 LIMIT 1
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 5ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:440:in   `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:256:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/drafts_controller.rb:16:in `index'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
```

Create Method.  This loads the index with params["format"]

```
def create
  @draft = Draft.create(draft_params)
  if @draft.save
    redirect_to drafts_path(@draft.id),notice: "Draft was successfully saved"
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

Form where create method is called

```
= form_for @draft, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
  #new-post-title
    = f.text_field :title, :value => "<h1><b>Title</b></h2>"

  #new-post-body
   = f.text_area :body, :value => "<p>Start writing</p>"

  .text-center
   = f.submit "New Draft", :class => "btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-round"
```

Comment: does it happen on `index` or on `create`??

Comment: Yes, good question, @UriAgassi.  If you want your create action to respond with javascript, then indeed you will want a create.js.erb file to correspond with this.  If, however, you truly want your index action to respond with javascript, you'll need a corresponding index.js.erb file.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is called `index.js.erb` I wrote the wrong file name.

Comment: please add server log trace. would be appreciated and easy for the answer giving people.

Comment: `Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 5ms!!`
The response type is not defined!!! its somehow related to mime types misleaded or needed to check from where you are sending your form! can you share that script and view part of form or link?

Comment: Rubyrider, I added the form and create method, which renders the index with params["format"]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For one, you're still specifying instance variables after your implicit call to `render` (in the `respond_to` block). Those instance variable declarations should be above any rendering.

Also, I've seen this happen in some browsers. You can get around it by declaring a dummy render block for the `html` type, so something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render(:text => "not implemented") }
  format.js
end
```

The `html` format block will likely never get called, but its declared nonetheless.

Comment: This worked for me with Rails 6!

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `remote: true` to the form helper since you are trying to submit the form using ajax.

```
= form_for @draft, :html => { :multipart => true }, remote: true do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
  #new-post-title
    = f.text_field :title, :value => "<h1><b>Title</b></h2>"

  #new-post-body
   = f.text_area :body, :value => "<p>Start writing</p>"

  .text-center
   = f.submit "New Draft", :class => "btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-round"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that your request are passing the correct headers.

In my case I'm on a rails API and my rspec test was calling the "default" type and not the implemented ones (json or csv). 
So I got the described error above.

To solve this I've just set the request headers in my tests and everything worked.

Answer (score -2):

This problem happened with me and sovled by just add

```
 respond_to :html, :json
```

to application_controller.rb file

You can Check Devise issues on Github: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2667